# How to add a search field on top of the master-detail(SplitContainer) without damage the navigation?

Tags: sapui5

My requirement is as the title. Basically there are three parts: Search Page, Master Page and Detail Page.

I want to include all of these pages into one page and make them navigable. I considered Splitter layout but it could loose the navigation?

Any ideas??

Best regards,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common requirement. I would suggest a full-screen layout, having a search bar and a result list on the landing/first page. From there, when a list item is clicked upon, you can navigate to the detail page.

Comment: Hi Krisho, yes this can be alternative. But what i want is just put these three parts in one page. Regarding the search and detail pages, i don't have too much to display...

Comment: The other approach is to have just master and detail page. On top of the master, you can have a single search field, which will search the master list.